# Sending Oracle AWS RDS logs to an S3 bucket

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I'm trying to send logs from an Oracle RDS hosted in Amazon to an S3 bucket. I'd like to send logs to the S3 bucket daily.

What would be a recommended course of action to achieve this? I'm not concerned if the data is compressed or in it's original format.

I'm also relatively new to AWS so I'm not fully aware of all the features that are available which could make this possible if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can do that:

1. Download the log file using instructions here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.html#USER_LogAccess.Procedural.Downloading and then upload it to S3
2. Automate the process of downloading the log file using CLI (check the above link for CLI commands) and upload to S3.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I think I'll have to take a look at trying to automate the process.